# Replacing legend and making distinct colours on scatter plot

Tags: r, plot

I am working on a countrywide data and trying to look at the relationship between disease count and flock size. I want to change the legend for scatter plot i.e to have names for the regions rather than the codes as appear on the plot posted here.I also want to make some improvements on the colours which represent the 8 regions so that there are some clear differences as it is a bit hard to differentiate between the current colours. Any suggestions on making the improvements on the plot?

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(log(Cases2012+1)~ Flock2012, data=orf, groups = Region.Coding, 
      auto.key =
         list(space = "right", points = TRUE))
```

portion of data:

```
Region Flock2012
    1   190
    2   343
    1   810
    3   1450
    1   1125
    3   1305
    1   750
    1   227
    3   1800
    1   1100
    2   1250
    1   362
    6   800
    2   559
    4   770
    1   900
    2   600
    1   860
    2   1450
    6   1014
    1   1870
    4   950
    1   1730
    5   353
    1   6000
    5   1150
    1   3100
    1   2400
    5   278
    2   444
    2   546
    7   775
    2   870
    5   690
    8   1032
    2   2351
    7   680
    3   430
    2   931
    8   1590
    2   70
    5   780
    2   1366
    2   1900
    4   730
    2   1860
    2   1032
    7   1700
    2   230
    2   301
    5   565
```

[image: Scatter plot for cases and flock 2012]

Tried this but plot not showing up

```
mycols <- c("red", "blue", "forestgreen", "gold", "black", "cyan", "darkorange", "darkred")
myregions <- c("East", "Midlands", "Wmidlands","NWest","NEast","Yorkshire","SEast","SWest")
xyplot(log(Flock2012+1)~ Flock2012, data=stack, groups = Regions, 
       col=mycols, pch=1,
       key=list(space="right",
                text=list(myregions),
                points=list(col=mycols, cex=1.5, pch=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. I would create a list of colours that you do want and a list of names of the regions.

```
mycols <- c("red", "blue", "forestgreen", "gold", "black", "cyan", "darkorange", "darkred")
myregions <- c("East", "Midlands", "Wmidlands","NWest","NEast","Yorkshire","SEast","SWest")
```

Then rather than use the `auto.key` option, use the key option for a bit more flexibility.

```
xyplot(log(Cases2012+1)~ Flock2012, data=orf, groups = Region.Coding, 
   col=mycols, pch=1,
key=list(space="right",
     text=list(myregions),
     points=list(col=mycols, cex=1.5, pch=1)))
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @outb4break. Coding runs fine except for not producing graph at the end. Could I be missing something? see coding at the end of main post

Comment: Obviously, you need to change the data to whatever the data frame is called on your machine. Also, I had to recode `groups = Regions.Coding`. You may want to change this back.

Comment: I've recoded the answer, please give a tick if it works.

Comment: thanks @outb4break. Not working yet plus no error message. think we are missing something as my original graph run just fine

Comment: Missing a couple of brackets on the end... This sort of thing you should be able to debug.

Comment: thanks @outb4break - worked ok bracket was the issue

Comment: colours still tricky though - no much different from original plot. Unless there is a way of increasing the plot sizes

Comment: This is entirely up to you now, please take a look at the vast list of colours available. A simple google search will point you in the right direction. And play around with `pch` parameter to change the style of the point. As always `?xyplot` will answer most of these questions.